# T-Sql to linq conversion issues (order by)

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I'm having a bit of issue converting the following t-sql statement to Linq (using 4.0 entity framework)

I'm getting

> Unable to cast the type
>   'System.Linq.IOrderedQueryable`1' to
>   type 'System.Linq.IQueryable`1'. LINQ
>   to Entities only supports casting
>   Entity Data Model primitive types.

T-Sql

```
    SELECT 
    I.Id
    , I.Name
FROM Inventory I
WHERE I.Id in 
    (
    select top 5 applicationId 
    from LastViewed 
    group by ApplicationId, SomeUserId
    having SomeUserId = @SomeUserId
    order by Max(id) desc
    )
```

This is what I have right now (with help from Linqer)

```
    Dim query As IQueryable(Of Inventory) =
        From d In ctx.Inventories
        Where
            ((From e In ctx.LastVieweds _
            Group e By _
              e.ApplicationId, _
              e.SomeUserId _
             Into g = Group _
            Where DfaitEdsId = user _
            Order By g.Max(Function(p) p.Id) Descending _
            Select New With { _
              ApplicationId _
            }).Take(5)).Contains(New With {.ApplicationId = d.Id}) _
        Select d
```

it currently crashes when I do this line.

```
query.ToList()
```

Thanks for your time.

Comment: I have a similar problem here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4416887/ef4-linq-2-entities-query-works-in-c-but-not-in-vb. I suspect the VB.Net compiler is to blame, since I could make it work in C#. Could you give a little more context, so we can try to repro your problem (pls explain what  `DfaitEdsId` and `user` are)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your 'problem' is in your very first line.  The query you have specified returns an `IOrderedQueryable(Of Inventory)` that you are trying to assign to a variable of type `IQueryable(Of Inventory)`.  You aren't getting the error until `query.ToList()` thanks to deferred execution.  You can let the compiler infer the type if you have 'option infer' set to on in your project and your query would be something like:

```
Dim query =
        From d In ctx.Inventories
        Where
            (From e In ctx.LastVieweds _
            Group e By _
              e.ApplicationId, _
              e.SomeUserId _
             Into g = Group _
            Where DfaitEdsId = user _
            Order By g.Max(Function(p) p.Id) Descending _
            Select ApplicationId Take 5 _
            ).Contains(d.Id) _
        Select d
```

Or you can just change the type of `query` to be `IOrderedQueryable(Of Inventory)`

Note:  What you have works fine in Linq to SQL, but Entities is much stricter when it comes to casting.

**Edit:**
Alright, let's try to dig a little deeper into this.  Tell me which line blows up with the following:

```
Dim innerList = (From e In ctx.LastVieweds _
                Group e By _
                e.ApplicationId, _
                e.SomeUserId _
                Into g = Group _
                Where DfaitEdsId = user _
                Order By g.Max(Function(p) p.Id) Descending _
                Select ApplicationId Take 5).ToList()
Dim query = (From d In ctx.Inventories
            Where innerList.Contains(d.Id) _
            Select d).ToList()
```

Don't forget to pare the results down a bit if enumerating the queries with 'ToList()' is too much.  The types of both variables are now `List(Of Inventory)`

Comment: thanks for the tip.  I had tried that and got the following error. Unable to cast the type 'System.Linq.IOrderedQueryable`1' to type 'System.Linq.IQueryable`1'. LINQ to Entities only supports casting Entity Data Model primitive types.  Any clue?

Comment: Is the query you listed the only place where you assign a value to query?

Comment: @diceGuyd30 yes to your previous comment.  I notice I posted the wrong new error message to your Answer.  I'm getting a compile error - Option Strict On disallows implicit conversions from System.Linq.Iqueryable(inventory) to System.Linq.IOrderedQueryable).  Everything under the Dim Query as IOrderedQueryable line gets underscored as a compile issue.

Comment: It looks like breaking it into seperate pieces did the trick.

Comment: I'm glad it worked, although you should now start removing the 'ToList()' calls to save on performance.  They are bringing the problem into the Linq to objects domain, instead of the Linq to entities domain where they really should be.  Glad it's working though!

Comment: Actually, I believe this answer is wrong. First, the result of the query is not of type IOrderedQueryable(Of Inventory). Even if it was, it would be safe to assign to a variable of type IQueryable(Of Inventory), since IOrderedQueryable(Of T) inherits from IQueryable(Of T). Second, and more importantly, moving the problem to the Linq 2 Objects space is not really a solution for the underlying problem, which is an exception thrown by Linq 2 Entities...

Comment: I'm not sure why you're bringing this back up.  My issue was solved and haven't looked back into it in a month..

Comment: @jeroenh it's true, bringing it into linq2objects is not a good fix. My intention was to find the specific offending piece of code by forcing materialization with ToList calls at different parts of the query.  I wanted to solve the actual problem (see that my edited 'answer' was actually a question) and would be happy to delve into it again,  but (as indicated by Lareau) Lareau was satisfied with the solution as it stood.

Comment: @diceguyd30 I believe there's a common underlying issue between this question and mine: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4416887/ef4-linq-2-entities-query-works-in-c-but-not-in-vb. Throws the same error in any case.